# How does Linux link device file with device driver? Does open() syscall eventually call device driver code?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I have a question about Linux device file and drivers, with my current understanding as the following:

1. When a user calls `open()` on some device file, at some point of time kernel will ask `inode` of the device file for the `read()`/`write()` function.
2. The device file was created by `udev` earlier, based on devices in `/sys` folder, meaning the `inode` of the device file should have `i_fop` field pointed to functions that know how to talk to the device, such as `read/write/mmap/ioctl/poll`. And that means each device file's `inode->i_fop` field should point to a different `file_operations` struct.

If so, the device driver will be providing these `read()`/`write()` functions, maybe the complete `file_operations` struct, including `read/write/mmap/ioctl`, etc.

Now, ULK says (in the description of `open()` syscall for device files) "sets the `i_fop` field of the `inode` object to the address of either the `def_blk_fops` or the `def_chr_fops` file operation table, according to the type of device file." And that means all block device files have the same `read()`/`write()` function, but then how can a user talk to *different* devices?

I also checked the `device_driver` struct, and indeed, there are no place to store file access functions, so how exactly an `open()` syscall performs its job using a device specific driver then? And where do device specific operation function live, if not in `device_driver`?

Comment: "How does Linux link device file with device driver?" - By **major** and **minor** **numbers**. Actually, any device file contains only these numbers. Only when device file is opened, Linux kernel checks whether a device with such numbers is registered, and calls corresponded functions for that device.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, so what does `device_driver` provide in this process, since the `cdev` struct already have `file_operations`?

Comment: If you look into `device_driver` [structure's definition](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.9.11/source/include/linux/device.h#L218) you will find that this structure describes completely different things than the file operations. It has e.g. `probe` function which binds the device with a driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following applies to opening character special devices.

When the file is opened, the `i_fop` pointer from the inode object gets copied to the `f_op` pointer of the file object. For character special devices, this points to `def_chr_fops`. `def_chr_fops.open` points to `chrdev_open`, so `chrdev_open(inode, filp)` is called when opening any character special device.

`chrdev_open` looks through its set of registered `struct cdev` objects which map the inode's major/minor numbers (combined into a `dev_t` number) to a particular registered `struct cdev`. If no matching `struct cdev` is found, it returns `-ENXIO`. Otherwise, it replaces the `f_op` pointer in the file object with the `ops` pointer from the `struct cdev`, which was set by the driver for the character special device.

If the file object's `f_op->open` is non-null, it is called and its return value is returned by `chrdev_open`. Otherwise, no special "open" handling is required for this character special device and 0 is returned.

If `chrdev_open` returns 0, the file object is in the "open" state and its `f_op` pointer points to the driver-specific file operations. The `open` syscall will eventually return a file descriptor. If `chrdev_open` returns a negative errno value, the file object will be destroyed, the `open` syscall will return -1 and `errno` will be set according to the return value from `chrdev_open`.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: A follow up question. It seems `cdev` contains the driver code and `cdev_add()` registers it to `cdev_map` kernel variable. They already link device file to a driver, but what about `device_driver` struct and `driver_register()` function, which seem to be related to sysfs? Does device driver need to call both `driver_register()` (directly or indirectly) and `cdev_add()` in driver's initialization code?

Comment: @QnA There are different aspects to a character device. A driver needs hardware devices which usually come by matching hardware device IDs on a bus, and that's where `driver_register` comes in. At the file access level, a device needs a device number and a set of file operations, so there are functions to reserve device numbers (`register_chrdev_region`, `alloc_chrdev_region`, `__register_chrdev`) and associate device numbers with file operations (`cdev_add`, `__register_chrdev`). A third aspect is creating the file path in "/dev" dynamically via `class_create` and `device_create`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, it knows which open function to call ultimately based on the major and minor numbers. You provide these or get ones automatically generated for you when you register your driver, whether character, block or tty.

What additionally happens with udev or systemd or mdev is that a device gets created under `/dev` automatically. There are cases with embedded distros (e.g. buildroot) and character devices where this won't happen automatically and you need to manually do it. I would suggest checking "Linux Device Drivers, 3rd edition, Chapter 3: Char Drivers" for more details.